# Environment properties are not passed to application in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying my Django project, database settings are not configured because `'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ` returns `false`. In fact no environment properties are available at the time of deployment. All these properties are available after the deployment.

Running `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment` returns following:

```
{"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE":"myApp.settings","PYTHONPATH":"/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin:$PYTHONPATH","RDS_DB_NAME":"ebdb","RDS_HOSTNAME":"xxxx.amazonaws.com","RDS_PASSWORD":"xxxx","RDS_PORT":"xxxx","RDS_USERNAME":"xxxx"}
```

All RDS prefixed properties are set but still somehow `os.environ` is unable to read it.

`setting.py` file:

```
# [...]

if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }

# [...]
```

Do I have to make any changes to make these properties available at the time of deployment?

Comment: We faced this exact same issue with our environment variables. After speaking with AWS support they informed us that special characters in our environment variables were breaking the deploy scripts for the variables and causing the issue. We resolved it by removing/changing the variables that had special characters. This is a particularly difficult to find because it doesn’t throw an error in the EB logs... Took forever to triage and get resolved.

Comment: Side note, specifically I think its an unescaped `’` that causes the deploy script to stop setting the variables on the instance. The variable will show correctly in the EB console but won’t actually get deployed to the environment correctly.

Comment: @hephalump; By special characters in env var you mean `_` in `RDS_DB_NAME` or any special characters in its value ?

Comment: No. I mean in the actual variable value, in ANY `env var` that is in EB. Our issue was that we had a backtick in one of our other `env var’s` (ie a special character in the actual variable value) which was escaping the `env var` deploy script... Although we received a successful deployment notification, it was not successful.

Comment: @hephalump; Yes. I too receive successful deployment message and no errors or warning in log files.

Comment: For us, we had to change the variable that had the backtick (it might have been a single quote) and this solved our issue.

Comment: I just checked all the values and I do not have any `\`` or `'` of `"` in any values. But I have other special characters: `. _ $ / : -`

Comment: Hmmm That was our issue, and AWS support solved it for us. Maybe try changing all values with special characters, to ones that don’t have special characters, and see if that solves the issue. Sorry it wasn’t more helpful.

Comment: @hephalump; Actually you gave me a heads up for this issue.

Comment: @hephalump The problem is the RDS_HOSTNAME, it has all those characters mentioned above and I can't change it.

Comment: Just looked at my support ticket from AWS. Instead of using the `EB environment variables`, another way to solve this issue is to use `AWS Secrets Manager` to store your vars...  They said: "One possible option would be to store the values in SSM Parameter Store or Secrets Manager and have the application load these values into memory from there. This way, the variables do not pose the potential of unexpectedly escaping strings from the deployment script."

Comment: @hephalump Let me try this and then I will update you.

Comment: @hephalump I tried with Secret Manager and again EB can't retrieve those secrets from SM. I ssh'ed into EB and ran a python script to get those secrets but I couldn't. But when I ran that script withe `sudo` permissions then I got all the secrets.

Comment: Have you set your instance IAM profile permissions to allow access to SM?

Comment: @hephalump I am the root user.

Comment: Yes, but when the instance is running it assumes a role which allows the instance to access AWS resources... In the EB console you should be able to find the role and then head over to IAM and give it permissions to access SM.

Comment: @hephalump I gave permission to IAM user. But then I had to run migrate command manually from EB instance to create all the tables in the database.

Comment: @hephalump I came up with some solutions along with yours and put it in the answer. Unfortunately none of them makes deploy seamless and they all require some manual work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like this is a serious bug and AWS doesn't care about it. There are few ways I came up with to make this work but all of them require logging into the EB environment and do some manual work.

### Solution 1

As suggested in comment by [hephalump](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3167238/hephalump)

1. Create an AWS secret manager
2. Check `IAM instance profile` in EB's environment `Configuration->Security->Edit`.
3. Then go to IAM user console and go to `Roles`. From there you can attach policy to the instance profile for secret manager.
4. Once it's done, deploy the project
5. Then login to the environment (`eb ssh environment_name`).
6. Go to `/var/app/current/` directory and run this command: `source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate`.
7. Finally run `python3 manage.py migrate`.

### Solution 2

1. Edit `.bash_profile` and add export these variables at the end of the file:

   ```
    export RDS_DB_NAME=your_dbname
    export RDS_USERNAME=user
    export RDS_PASSWORD=pass
    export RDS_HOSTNAME=host_endpoint
    export RDS_PORT=3306
   ```
2. Run `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. Now you can deploy your project.

### Solution 3

1. Set all environment properties in EB environment's configuration. (Go to `Configuration->Software->Edit->Environment properties` and add the key and values).
   [image]

2. Add this snippet at the beginning of `settings.py`

```
    from pathlib import Path
    import os
    import subprocess
    import ast


    def get_environ_vars():
        completed_process = subprocess.run(
            ['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config', 'environment'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            text=True,
            check=True
        )

        return ast.literal_eval(completed_process.stdout)
```

3. Go to Database section and replace it with this snippet

   ```
    if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
            '    ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                 'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
                 'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
                 'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
                 'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
                 'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
    else:
        env_vars = get_environ_vars()
        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': env_vars['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': env_vars['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': env_vars['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': env_vars['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': env_vars['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
   ```
4. Deploy the project.
5. Login to the environment (`eb ssh environment_name`).
6. Go to `/var/app/current/` directory and run this command: `source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate`.
7. Finally run `python3 manage.py migrate`.

### Conclusion:

**Solution 1** is little *complex* and secret manager is *not free* (30 days trial only).
**Solution 2** is *simplest* one but I do *not recommend* tempering any file manually on EB.
**Solution 3** is a *clean solution* which I will use. This solution also takes care of this bug fix in future.

Comment: Why do you use activate? Just run the venv python interpreter with the path to manage.py and command: `/var/app/venv/*/bin/python /var/app/current/manage.py migrate`.

Comment: To activate the virtual environment

Comment: You don't need to. Activation is nothing more than `PATH` mangling to get the right interpreter selected for **interactive** use.

Comment: I never understood why they made it sound and look so magical, when the only code that matters is `PATH=/path/to/venv/bin:$PATH`. The subshell, PROMPT mangling, etc, is all to enhance interactive use, but it also makes "activating a virtual environment" sound like a mandatory process to get anything done with it.

Comment: @Melvyn Yes you are right. This can be done without activating virtual environment,  but activating it and then doing the work is another way of doing it but for sure it is not mandatory.

Comment: I guess I don't get why you need to ssh and cannot do fully automated deploys. :)

Comment: @Melvyn Didn't get it?

Comment: I tried this in `.config`: `container_commands:
    01_migrate:
        command: "/var/app/venv/*/bin/python3 manage.py migrate
        --noinput"
        leader_only: true`
Build failed.

Comment: If you have no log of the results, then it gets really hard. At first glance, `cwd` is not where manage.py is. Or the expansion of the '*' does not work with all passing around of shell commands from one file format to the next. If this ultimately gets translated to a docker RUN command, then get the container running locally first, so you can debug it better. And finally, since it's containerized, consider ditching the venv and using the container provided python. That way you know if the venv is a factor.

Answer (score 4):

To use Environment properties in the system eg. run Symfony commands (using envs) you can simply run this:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"export \(.key)='\(.value|tostring)'\")|.[]" >> /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile
```

It will add all your props in .bash_profile so when you log in via SSH they will be all set. Of course it would be good to add this in .ebextensions/*.config under commands: section.

Comment: This will populate `/home/ec2-user/.bash_profile` file with the environment variables on every deployment.

Answer (score 2):

The official AWS solution for making environmental variables available from the EC2 level also fixes this problem:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/

Comment: It says in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html#python-rds-connect) that these variables can be accessed by the application using `os.environ`. But unfortunately it can't.

Answer (score 0):

based on the article metioned by @Jarek.D [AWS Elastic-Beanstalk env Variables Shell](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/) we made an extra approach so you can get the env varibales read with the os.environment.get() method of python in the project. we created a process.sh file that executes:

```
source /etc/profile.d/sh.local
source /var/app/venv/[your_staging]/bin/activate
python your_file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this by:

1. Encoding my secrets with base64 encoder
2. Setting the environment variables with encoded values
3. Decoding the encoded variables while reading inside Django settings

Example- Assuming we want to read environment variable `RDS_PASSWORD='@#$%^&'` in our service

**Step 1:** Encoding our password with base64. Can be done using python as follows

```
In [1]: import base64

In [2]: password = b'@#$%^&'

In [3]: base64.b64encode(password)
Out[3]: b'QCMkJV4m'
```

**Step 2:** Setting the environment variable in Elastic Beanstalk environment configuration (Go to your EB environment `Configuration->Updates, monitoring, and logging->Edit->Environment properties`)
[image]

**Step 3:** Add logic to decode and read this variable inside your Django services settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': base64.b64decode(os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD']).decode('utf-8'),
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

Characters present in base64 encoded string

- [A-Z]
- [a-z]
- [0-9]
- [+, /, = (For Padding)]

[Characters supported by EB environment variables values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console)

- **Values** can contain any alphanumeric characters, white space, and the following symbols: `_ . : / = + \ - @ ' "`

When compared to other solutions in this post, I find this solution much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following to expand the environment values into the current shell environment:

```
eval $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"export \(.key)='\(.value|tostring)'\")|.[]")
```

This will put the Elasticbeanstalk variables into the current similarly to if you exported them:

```
export Xmx='12888m'
export HEAP_DUMP_PATH='/heapdumps'
export ENVIRONMENT='qa'
```